# Couldn't build egg file for pyarrow

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmake, aws-glue, pyarrow

**Issue:**

Couldn't build egg file for pyarrow, tried with  0.12.1 and 0.13 versions of pyarrow. Could you please help me to understand if I miss anything?

```
$ python setup.py bdist_egg
```

**Log Trace:**

```
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing entry points to pyarrow.egg-info/entry_points.txt
writing top-level names to pyarrow.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing requirements to pyarrow.egg-info/requires.txt
writing pyarrow.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to pyarrow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'pyarrow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*~' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '#*' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '.DS_Store' found anywhere in distribution
no previously-included directories found matching '.asv'
writing manifest file 'pyarrow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/egg
running install_lib
running build_py
copying pyarrow/_generated_version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-x86_64-3.5/pyarrow
running build_ext
-- Running cmake for pyarrow
cmake -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/Users/pratheek/egg_test/bin/python  -DPYARROW_BOOST_USE_SHARED=on -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=release /Users/pratheek/Downloads/pyarrow-0.12.1
unable to execute 'cmake': No such file or directory
error: command 'cmake' failed with exit status 1
```

**Error:**

```
error: command 'cmake' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error means that you don't have `cmake` installed on your system. As you are on macOS, you can use Homebrew to install it via `brew install cmake`.

In general, you should not build egg files from `pyarrow` but rather wheels as eggs are considered deprecated.

Comment: The reason I'm building pyarrow egg is to use pyarrow in AWS Glue Python Shell Job. Currently, AWS Glue - Python shell jobs support only eggs. Kindly help me to resolve this issue